# Convert string to Multiline in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, string, label

I want to fit a text to a specific screen size. The text is editable - change text, change font size, font color, font family.

For Example:

> "For God loved the world so much that he gave his only-begotten Son, so that everyone exercising faith in him might not be destroyed but have everlasting life. For God loved the world so much that he gave his only-begotten Son, so that everyone exercising faith in him might not be destroyed but have everlasting life."

is a string which is very long and it's single line.

I want it to be put in a label like this.

> "For God loved the world so much that
>   he gave his only-begotten Son, so that
>   everyone exercising faith in him might
>   not be destroyed but have everlasting
>   life. For God loved the world so much
>   that he gave his only-begotten Son, so
>   that everyone exercising faith in him
>   might not be destroyed but have everlasting life."

VB.Net. Any Suggestion?

Comment: WinForms? WPF? Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
label3.MaximumSize = New Size(100, 0)
label3.AutoSize = True
```

Comment: Let him get back to you when he's tested it. Don't stress, he might not have read it yet. -- What I wonder though is why you post C# and VB.NET code when this is only a VB.NET question?

Comment: Not stressing him, if not working then can help him to resolve the issue. Yes C# code also, for new developers searching the same problem. You could have just let it be there, why had do delete it :)

Comment: Not stressing him, but stressing _it_. He will most likely respond when he finds that it works or not. -- The C# code is superfluous since the OP has only tagged this with VB.NET. Others searching for C# answers will most likely not find this because Stack Overflow's tag system is designed to (even in search engines) match the language/tag you're looking for in as good way as possible. Answers should mostly be aimed toward the asker of the question and the question itself, not other users. Besides if someone were to find it they could easily convert that snippet to C#.

Comment: Thanks Vincent for your valuable comments :)

Comment: Wow guys! It worked!! I never thought it could be that simple. I was cracking my head to accomplish this manually trying to go with .length dividing it line by line and forming it to finalstring. But the above code was just 2 lines! Thank you so much!

Comment: Good to know it worked for you. You can mark it as answer :)